# Creating a circular progress bar around an image

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to create a circular progress bar  `<http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvjjKL>`[this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvjjKL)`<a href ="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvjjKL">this</a>` but with an image inside the circle .. I can only find solutions which have text inside the circle , how can i include an image tag inside it instead... If anyone has implemented it , do share your code .
Thanks

Comment: I think that first you have to find the progress bar that you want, and then post the example here and ask for help to set image instead text.

Comment: You might want to review [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow. Also, whether your question is [**On-Topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the codepen you linked, just replace the span with an image.

The parent div of the image has to have: `overflow: hidden` and the image should have the same size as the parent div.

The rest is literally given in the code you gave as example.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVmmqa)

Comment: Thanks, I was not implementing with the proper image size .. got confused with the results

Comment: Sure, no problem :) In the future though, try to mention what you already tried and where you got stuck. It's a lot easier for us to pinpoint the origin of your problem and you will get better answers.